# How do I get more control over the NodePorts my Service assigns to my Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Deployment with 5 replicas. All have ssh and telnet. They should not be load balanced. I would like each to select from a predictable list of 5.

Here is my Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myapp:1.0
        ports:
        - name: ssh
          protocol: TCP
          containerPort: 22
        - name: telnet
          protocol: TCP
          containerPort: 23
```

This is my Service with invalid nodePort values for illustrative purposes.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: ssh
    port: 22
    nodePort: [30022, 30122, 30222, 30322, 30422, 30522]
  - name: telnet
    port: 23
    nodePort: [30023, 30123, 30223, 30323, 30423, 30523]
```

I am hoping to be able to accomplish 2 things:

1. Each pod replica instance will only get an ssh port from [30022, 30122, 30222, 30322, 30422, 30522] and a telnet port from [30023, 30123, 30223, 30323, 30423, 30523]
2. A pod replica instance that gets an ssh port of 30022 also gets the telnet port 30023. A pod replica instance that gets an ssh port of 30122 gets a telnet port of 30123 and so on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand kubernetes services, that trick is not possible.

What could help you to have preserved hostnames is a StatefulSet.
[See more here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/)

> The Pods’ ordinals, hostnames, SRV records, and A record names have
>   not changed, but the IP addresses associated with the Pods may have
>   changed. In the cluster used for this tutorial, they have. This is why
>   it is important not to configure other applications to connect to Pods
>   in a StatefulSet by IP address.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with StatefulSet with replicas and a multiple services looking for the predictable pod name of each replica: myapp-0, myapp-1, myapp-2, etc

Answer (score 0):

If the pods (quote) "...should not be load balanced", each pod is to be accessed on different NodePort ports, the order of starting them up doesn't matter...you can:

- Create 5 identical Deployment-s, say, myapp-1 thru myapp-5, with 1 replica each.
- Create a Service for each Deployment making sure the selector is correct for each myapp-1 thru myapp-5 Deployment-s. Configure each Service with the concrete nodePort-s for ssh and telnet as you wish.

It is to note that this way each pod will be independent of the rest and pods cannot be scaled by simply adding a replica. Still, if configured, the pods will be rescheduled and restarted in case of pod or node failure.